# How to properly use the @Param annotation of Mybatis

Tags: annotations, mybatis

I didn't use @Param annotation at first, this is my mapper.java

```
public void changeUserAuth(Integer userId,int identity);
```

, and this is my mapper.xml

```
<update id="changeUserAuth">
    update user
    <set>
        <if test="identity != 0">identity = #{identity}</if>
    </set>
    <where>
        <if test="userId != 0">userId = #{userId}</if>
    </where>
</update>
```

then it works correctly!I continue to write like this, as follows:

```
//this's mapper.java
public void updateUserStatus(Integer userId);

<!--this is mapper.xml>
<update id="changeUserAuth">
    update user
    set deleteFlag= true
    <where>
        <if test="userId != 0">userId = #{userId}</if>
    </where>
</update>
```

however,it gave an error,the message is

> There is no getter for property named 'userId' in 'class.java.lang.Integer'

I can understand that mybatis cannot parse the Integer, but why it is not an error like my first use,  just because I have an int type Parameter? In the second method, I have to use @Param annotation

Comment: Actually, both should work if you use MyBatis 3.5.2 or later.  See this [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1487) if you are interested.

Comment: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency> ` this is my pom.xml,in fact,it's version is 3.5.1

Comment: Yes, so both should work if you use mybatis-spring-boot-starter 2.1.0 or later. Please see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 15):

Here is how you reference parameters in MyBatis statements.

I'll use this POJO in the following explanation.

```java
public class User {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  //...
}
```

---

### When `@Param` is used

If you add `@Param` annotation on a parameter, you can use the specified name to reference the parameter. This is the simplest case.

A few examples:

```java
List<USer> select(@Param("id") Integer userId, @Param("name") String userName);

void insert(@Param("record") User user);
```

```xml
<select id="select" resultType="User">
  select * from users
  <where>
    <if test="id != null">and id = #{id}</if>
    <if test="name != null">and name = #{name}</if>
  </where>
</select>

<insert id="insert">
  insert into users (id, name) values
    (#{record.id}, #{record.name})
</insert>
```

### Without `@Param`

If there is no `@Param`, it depends on several conditions.

#### When the mapper method takes only one parameter [1] and ...

1. ... the sole parameter is assignable to `java.util.List`, you can reference the parameter as `list`.

   ```java
   List<User> selectByIds(List<Integer> ids);
   ```

   ```xml
   <select id="select" resultType="User">
     select * from users
     where id in (
       <foreach item="x" collection="list" separator=",">
         #{x}
       </foreach>
     )
   </select>
   ```
2. ... the sole parameter is assignable to `java.util.Collection`, you can reference the parameter as `collection`.

   ```java
   List<User> selectByIds(Set<Integer> ids);
   ```

   ```xml
   <select id="select" resultType="User">
     select * from users
     where id in (
       <foreach item="x" collection="collection" separator=",">
         #{x}
       </foreach>
     )
   </select>
   ```
3. ... there is a type handler mapped to the sole parameter (i.e. the parameter is `String`, `Integer`, etc.).

- With MyBatis 3.5.2 and later, you can reference the parameter using any name (you should use sensible names for obvious reasons, though). e.g.

  ```java
  List<User> select(Integer id);
  ```

  ```xml
  <select id="select" resultType="User">
    select * from users
    <where>
      <if test="x != null">and id = #{y}</if>
    </where>
  </select>
  ```
- With MyBatis 3.5.1

  - you can reference the parameter with any name in `#{}`.
  - you must reference the parameter as `_parameter` in `${}`, `test` attribute of `<if />` and `<when />` and `value` attribute of `<bind />`. This is why your second example throws exception.

    ```java
    List<User> select(Integer id);
    ```

    ```xml
    <select id="select" resultType="User">
      select * from users
      <where>
        <if test="_parameter != null">and id = #{z}</if>
      </where>
    </select>
    ```

1. ... there is no type handler mapped to the sole parameter (i.e. the parameter is POJO or `Map<String, ?>`), you can reference the parameter properties directly with their names (or the keys if the parameter is a `Map`).

   ```java
   void insert(User user);
   ```

   ```xml
   <insert id="insert">
     insert into users (id, name) values
       (#{id}, #{name})
   </insert>
   ```

#### When the mapper method takes multiple parameters

1. If the project is compiled with '-parameters' [compiler option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), you can reference the parameters using their names declared in the method signature. This is your first example.

   ```java
   List<USer> select(Integer userId, String userName);
   ```

   ```xml
   <select id="select" resultType="User">
     select * from users
     <where>
       <if test="userId != null">and id = #{userId}</if>
       <if test="userName != null">and name = #{userName}</if>
     </where>
   </select>
   ```
2. Otherwise, you can reference the parameters using the names implicitly assigned by MyBatis i.e. `arg0`, `arg1`, ... (I would not recommend this as it's fragile and error-prone).

   ```java
   List<USer> select(Integer userId, String userName);
   ```

   ```xml
   <select id="select" resultType="User">
     select * from users
     <where>
       <if test="arg0 != null">and id = #{arg0}</if>
       <if test="arg1 != null">and name = #{arg1}</if>
     </where>
   </select>
   ```

---

[1] `RowBounds` and `ResultHandler` does not count.