# how to dynamically update fields in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a class Foo with fields bar, baz, and buz and an XML mapping file:

How would I write a generic update mapper that will allow me to update records for a non-null value of one of of the fields for a given where clause?

e.g. something like

UPDATE public.foo set
        
           bar = #{bar},
        
        
           baz = #{baz},
        
        
           buz = #{buz},
        
    
   
        
            #{item}
        
    
    
My Mapper class looks like:

```
void bulkUpdate(Foo foo, @Param("userIds") Collection<Long> userIds);
```

But i get an error in the XMl because it doesn't look like I can pass the object and a @Param...

Any ideas?

Comment: Short answer: Add `@Param("foo")` to the first method argument and reference its properties with `foo.` prefix i.e. `#{foo.bar}` instead of `#{bar}`. Long answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811574/1261766).