# How to use conditional where clauses with Mybatis using annotations?

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

My service is as follows,

```
public List<ApplicationConfig> find(@RequestBody String type){
    List<WhereClauseParams> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    WhereClauseParams condition = new WhereClauseParams("type", type);
    conditions.add(condition);
    return applicationConfigRepository.find(conditions);
}

public List<ApplicationConfig> findById(@RequestBody String id){
    List<WhereClauseParams> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    WhereClauseParams condition = new WhereClauseParams("id", id);
    conditions.add(condition);
    return applicationConfigRepository.find(conditions);
}
```

WhereClauseParams is a class I've created as a common object that can be used across, wherever needed, and is as below,

```
public class WhereClauseParams {
private String column;
private String sqlOperator = "=";
private Object value;
```

with the rest of the code being getter setters and constructors.
My mapper is as follows,

```
@Repository
@Mapper
public interface ApplicationConfigRepository {
    @Select("<script>" +
            "select id, name, type, isActive, createdBy, createdOn, updatedBy, updatedOn " +
            "from application_config " +
            "where 1=1 " +
            "<if test=\"type!=null\"> " +
            " and type=#{type} " +
            " </if>" +
            "<if test=\"id!=null\"> " +
            " and id=#{id} " +
            " </if>" +
            "</script>")
    public List<ApplicationConfig> find(List<WhereClauseParams> params);
```

I've figured this much of the code out using references from stackoverflow and mybatis docs, but I'm not being able to understand how to pass the parameters to the mapper. If I pass a single string parameter, it works fine, but if I want to make it work conditionally, I have to pass an object, but what type of object?
The above code gives the following error when I call the find method,

```
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Parameter 'type' not found. Available parameters are [collection, list, params]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$ParamMap.get(MapperMethod.java:210) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicContext$ContextAccessor.getProperty(DynamicContext.java:119) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:3344) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:121) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.ASTNotEq.getValueBody(ASTNotEq.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:586) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:550) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:46) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:34) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:39) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:320) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:88) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:142) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:425) ~[mybatis-spring-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224) ~[mybatis-spring-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:142) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86) ~[mybatis-3.5.13.jar:3.5.13]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241) ~[spring-aop-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.group.firstResponder.repository.impl.ApplicationConfigImpl.find(ApplicationConfigImpl.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
at com.group.firstResponder.controller.CommonController.findConfig(CommonController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.78.jar:9.0.78]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

P.S. I've also tried changing the query in the mapper to

```
@Select("<script>" +
            "select id, name, type, isActive, createdBy, createdOn, updatedBy, updatedOn " +
            "from application_config " +
            "where 1=1 " +
            "<if test=\"params.type!=null\"> " +
            " and type=#{params.type} " +
            " </if>" +
            "<if test=\"params.id!=null\"> " +
            " and id=#{params.id} " +
            " </if>" +
            "</script>")
```

...didn't help..

Edit 1:

As per ave's suggestion, I changed the service to,

```
public List<ApplicationConfig> find(@RequestBody String type){
    List<WhereClauseParams> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    WhereClauseParams condition = new WhereClauseParams("type", type);
    conditions.add(condition);
    return applicationConfigRepository.find(Map.of("type", type));
}

public List<ApplicationConfig> findById(@RequestBody String id){
    List<WhereClauseParams> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    WhereClauseParams condition = new WhereClauseParams("id", id);
    conditions.add(condition);
    return applicationConfigRepository.find(Map.of("id", id));
}
```

and the mapper to

```
@Select("<script>" +
        "select id, name, type, isActive, createdBy, createdOn, updatedBy, updatedOn " +
        "from application_config " +
        "where 1=1 " +
        "<if test=\"params.type!=null\"> " +
        " and type=#{params.type} " +
        " </if>" +
        "<if test=\"params.id!=null\"> " +
        " and id=#{params.id} " +
        " </if>" +
        "</script>")
public List<ApplicationConfig> find(Map params);
```

This gave the following error,

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'params.type!=null'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "type")
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:97)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:439)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:142)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.find(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.group.firstResponder.repository.impl.ApplicationConfigImpl.create(ApplicationConfigImpl.java:43)
    at com.group.firstResponder.controller.CommonController.createConfig(CommonController.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'params.type!=null'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "type")
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.OgnlCache.getValue(OgnlCache.java:48)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.ExpressionEvaluator.evaluateBoolean(ExpressionEvaluator.java:32)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.IfSqlNode.apply(IfSqlNode.java:34)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.lambda$apply$0(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.MixedSqlNode.apply(MixedSqlNode.java:32)
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.DynamicSqlSource.getBoundSql(DynamicSqlSource.java:39)
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.MappedStatement.getBoundSql(MappedStatement.java:320)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:425)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "type")
```

Comment: `List` does not let you reference its elements by name, you know. You should probably use `Map` e.g. `...find(Map.of("type", type))`.

Comment: @ave thank you for the suggestion, but I got an error with this approach,

org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error evaluating expression 'params.type!=null'. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.ognl.OgnlException: source is null for getProperty(null, "type")

Comment: If the `Map` is the sole parameter of the method, you can just write `<if test=\"type != null\"> and type = #{type} </if>`. If not, please add the updated mapper method/statement definition.

Comment: I'll add it to the question, as I'm not being able to format it correctly here..

Comment: Try `type` instead of `params.type`.

Comment: @ave Hey man.. if you're ever in Mumbai, please let me know. I'd love to buy you a beer!

Comment: also, could you please add your suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it complete?

Comment: I'm glad to know it helped!  I added an answer with a few extra suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `java.util.List`, it's not possible to reference its elements by name, so it probably is better to use `java.util.Map`.

A few suggestions:

- If you are using Java 15 or higher, you can use "text block" to simplify the annotation value.
- `where 1=1` works fine in most cases, but `<where>` might come in handy in some cases. It automatically removes unnecessary `and` or `or`.

```java
@Select("""
    <script>
      select id, name, ...
      from application_config
      <where>
        <if test="type != null">
          and type=#{type}
        </if>
        <if test="id != null">
          and id=#{id}
        </if>
      </where>
    </script>
    """)
List<ApplicationConfig> find(Map<String, Object> params);
```

The code that calls this method would look something like this:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("type", type);
applicationConfigRepository.find(params);
```

---

You might also want to take a look at the following answer which explains "how to reference parameters in MyBatis".
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59811574/1261766